# Find and Replace 2 new lines in a string

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a form and I want to find when there is 2 new lines in the text. I mean `\n\n` or `<br/><br/>` toguether. In his is an example I try to find the separation between Second and Third paragraph:

```
First paragraph  
Second paragraph 

Third paragraph
```

I can find one `"\n"` and replace, when there is just one new line:

```
$p = str_replace("\n", "replace", $text);
```

But I cannot find when there is 2 toguether. I try `\n\n` and `<br/><br/>` and it does not work:

```
$p = str_replace("\n\n", "replace", $text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead take help of `preg_replace`:

```
 $p = preg_replace('/(\r?\n){2}/', "replace", $text)
```

This will replace 2 consecutive new line characters with word `replace`. It will also cover Windows new line characters i.e. `\r\n`

Comment: It works very well, thank you. Can you explain please:/(\r?\n){2}/ or where can I find information about how to write this kind of expressions?

Comment: Nrc: A Google search for **regular expression** or **regex** should turn up some useful resources.

Comment: `\r?\n` means `\n` optionally preceded by `\r` and `(\r?\n){2}` means 2 occurrences of them.